# Query two models in Django into one queryset

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I have two models in my django app:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name="books")
```

Now I need to create a view that will make one query for regex to both of the models, find the ones that are matching and display them in template.
If I do:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    queryset = Person.objects.filter(name__icontains="a")
    book_queryset = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains="a")
```

I get an error that ListView accepts only one queryset.
What is the typical solution to such problem?

Comment: Sometimes it is better to accept what it is telling you and look for an alternative. Perhaps create another model that references _both_ those models and returns _that_ instead? What would be the data structure that the list view currently returns if your code was working? [Person, Person, Book, Book, Person, Person]? You'd have to do a lot of extra work in the UI to deal with that melange.

Comment: Sorry, i have forgot to add that the book and Person have many to many relationship. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something a little bit different here:

```
class SearchListView(ListView):
    queryset = Person.objects.filter(name__icontains="a")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_queryset'] = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains="a")
        return context
```

Then in your view you can do somenting like the following:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <p>{{object}}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% for object in book_queryset %}
    <p>{{object}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The reason why the way you are using is not working is because `ListView` inherit from `MultipleObjectMixin` the `queryset` property and that property is passed to `object_list` context variable in the template, that happens under the hood and if you want to pass more context variables to the template you need to follow the approach I shared.